# Elegant way of stripping string of currency characters?

Tags: swift, currency

Currently Im receiving a string from a service that contains currency characters (Ex. "$123.44", "123,44 €"). I would like to strip these stings of their currency characters in order to perform some calculations on these prices (adding money, subtracting money...etc).

I know I could replace occurrences of certain characters and then re-add them later after the calculations, but I get the impression that there might be a better solution out there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSNumberFormatter` to convert a formatted price into a `Double` value

```
func getNumber(formattedPrice: String, localeID: String) -> Double? {
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: localeID)
    return formatter.numberFromString(formattedPrice)?.doubleValue
}
```

but you'll need to specify the `locale`

```
getNumber("$123.44", localeID: "en_US") // 123.44
getNumber("123,44€", localeID: "it_IT") // 123.44
getNumber("£123.44", localeID: "en_UK") // 123.44
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `NSCharacterSet` to root out those characters, like this:

```
var dollarStr = "$1.50"
var yuanStr = "¥18.25"
var euroStr = "20.75 €"

let strArray = [dollarStr, yuanStr, euroStr]

let charSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "$¥€ ")

for str in strArray {
    let trimmedStr = str.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(charSet)
    print(trimmedStr)
}
```

prints out :

```
1.50
18.25
20.75
```